# RemoveExistingProducts decision

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

In the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx we see old files are removed. Could please tell us what this mean, how old files are idenfied?

The question is:
"How does RemoveExistingProducts know what to remove?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the property UpgradeCode. Here are more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry but didn't answear my question. I know how upgradecode works, I was interested what this mean on file level. More concret situation. I have version 1.2.5 installed, I upgrade to 1.2.6 changing the productcode+version (major upgrade) and because I use RemoveExistingProducts after InstallFinalize my dll are removed from setup and I don't undestand why? If I test in upgrade from 1.1.x to 1.2.6 it works.

Comment: So you are interested in the file versioning rules, i.e. the one which the OS uses to decide if a file is updated or not? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx